# How do I use nodemon's --inspect option correctly?

Tags: node.js, discord, nodemon

Preface: Attempting to write a discord bot and I have no experience with Node and a small amount with javascript with HTML.

When I input `nodemon --inspect Version 1.0.js` into powershell it just gives me this as the return message:

```
Usage: nodemon [nodemon options] [script.js] [args]

See "nodemon --help" for more.
```

I am getting most of my starting resources from this How-To Geek article: https://www.howtogeek.com/364225/how-to-make-your-own-discord-bot/. I don't know how reputible they are when it comes to coding but I thought I'd try it.

Comment: Put your filename in quotes if possible or better yet remove the space in the filename(rename the file to get rid of the space). While spaces are allowed in filenames, nodemon and other utilities like npm or even programming languages like python or node do not handle spaces in filename very well.

Comment: yep. that did it. thats something that didn't even cross my mind for some reason. thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> If no script is given, nodemon will test for a package.json file and
>   if found, will run the file associated with the main property (ref).
>
> You can also pass the inspect flag to node through the command line as
>   you would normally:

```
nodemon --inspect ./server.js 80
```